# Visual Studio 2008 WPF Project error "project type is not supported"

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm running Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2008 (SP1).  Yesterday I came across an issue when creating WPF projects.  I don't know if I've created any other WPF projects since I installed Win7.

First of all, in the Create Project dialog, the project type says "csWPFApplication" which is weird enough and I never noticed before.  When I try creating the project I get 2 Package Load Failure errors for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Internal.WPFFlavor.WPFPackage and then a message that "The project file ... cannot be opened.  The project type is not supported by this installation.

I tried a number of different suggestions from Google and even uninstalled/reinstalled to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: What version is your Visual Studio showing?  Is it 9.0.30729.1 SP?  I've seen this problem with an MSDN installed version of VS 2008 and it was corrected by applying the service pack, though it sounds like you already have SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Visual Studio with.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>   /resetskippkgs

I would also try to just create a blank solution/WPF project. and then add the files from your old project one at a time, and see if you still get the error.

If that doesn't work, I would try to uninstall and reinstall .NET 3.5 which looks it could be corrupt.

Comment: I tried the resetskippkgs flag.  This error appears when I create a WPF project.  I tried uninstalling .NET through Add/Remove windows components also.